# would this question be on topic, or spamming?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

I want to ask about these kids that apparently have sued Westlake High. There was a senior who was suspended for self defense. He's suing the school. I heard the court was going to hear his case. This is really another question about the zero tolerance policy, but really I'm asking if anyone knows if there will be further news of this court case anytime soon. I heard it would return in April. This lawsuit was threatened in February.

http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2014/02/13/are-you-the-one-harassing-my-little-girl-thats-what-a-father-asked-right-before-things-spun-out-of-control/

Anyways, I'm wondering if that court case would be on topic to politics on stack exchange. Also, is it just spamming with questions to post a second question on this subject? If so, I think there's other stuff I could be posting on the site.

Comment: It's certainly possible for a question to be neither on-topic nor spamming.

Comment: Where would it be safe to post though? I really don't want to post off topic? Or is it just off topic anywhere on the site? I mean, there has to be some place on the stack network where this is safe right?

Comment: In my opinion, it is on topic.  What you really should be careful about is if the question is focused enough and clear enough for SE.  It's more likely to get closed as too broad or unclear what you're asking than as off topic

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 points to make

1. There's nothing wrong with posting multiple questions about the same subject or event.  Just make sure that they aren't duplicates of each-other.
2. It's hard to say from just this meta question, but there's a chance that your question might get closed as "**unclear what you're asking**".  If your question is something vague and unspecific such as "**does anyone have any news about this trial**", then it will be hard to formulate a correct answer, even if the answerer does know the information that you need.

Comment: Thx. Would it be okay to reword my question in another meta post? Or should I just reword it when actually asking?

Comment: @JackTrustsYou Re-word it when asking.  If you don't get it right the first time, you can always edit it.

Comment: @JackTrustsYou and make sure you know exactly what kind of information you want before you ask.  If you don't really have a clear question in your head, than it'd be hard to write one as a post.

Comment: Thx. I appreciate that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "does anyone know" is "yes". The judge clearly knows. If you want to know what the latest status is, just ask "what is the latest publically known status as of today".